# Smallest rectangle that fits the first 10 rectangles

Tags: geometry, optimization, packing

What is the area of the smallest rectangle that can fit 10 rectangles with areas 1 to 10, inclusive? Rectangles must have integer sides and cannot overlap.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This answer seems a bit too trivial to be the intended one, but:

> The answer is 55.

> The minimum area must be 1+2+3+4+5+6+7+8+9+10=55

> This can be done by taking rectangles of dimensions 1$\times$1, 2$\times$1,..., 10$\times$1 and arranging them in a straight line to get a rectangle with dimensions 55$\times$1

Comment: Rot13(5k11 vf nyfb rkgerzryl fvzcyr (ebjf bs 10+1, 9+2, 8+3 rgp))

Comment: Oh that's right, then it's just a poorly framed question

Comment: of course you are right. I completely stuffed up this question. It should have been a square...

Answer (score 2):

One example of smallest perimeter rectangle

> Rectangle 8x7, with one empty 1x1 square, which is the nerest to an 8x8 square

> [image]

Comment: that's very nice! This is the question I should have asked.